# Explain behaviors in mapping auto incremented composite id sequence with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `SomeEntity` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `subid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`subid`),
```

I have a entity class with an auto increment field in it.I want to read auto increment id assigned to it when it gets persisted

Annotations on getter are as below

```
  private long id;
   private int subid;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue **//How do i correct this to have multiple rows with same id and different subid**
  @Column(name = "id")
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "subid")
  public int getSubid() {
    return subid;
  }
```

I want to have entities as

```
id 1 subid 0 
id 1 subid 1
id 1 subid 2
id 2 subid 0
```

subid is default 0 in database and i am incrementing it programmatically on updates to that row. 
I tried the solution as in this SO post 
[JPA - Returning an auto generated id after persist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732453/jpa-returning-an-auto-generated-id-after-persist)

```
 @Transactional
  @Override
  public void daoSaveEntity(SomeEntity entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
  }
```

Now outside this transaction I am trying to get the auto increment id assigned

```
      @Override
      public long serviceSaveEntity(SomeEntity entity) {
        dao.daoSaveEntity(entity);
        return entity.getId();
      }
```

I am calling this from a web service

```
  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response createEntity(SomeEntity entity) {
```

The update method is as below

```
 @Transactional
  public void updateReportJob(SomeEntity someEntity) {

    Query query =
        entityManager
.createQuery("UPDATE SomeEntity SET state=:newState WHERE id = :id");
    query.setParameter("newState","PASSIVE");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    query.executeUpdate();
    double rand = Math.random();
    int i = (int) (rand * 300);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(i);  //only to simulate concurrency issues
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<Integer> resList =
        entityManager.createQuery("select max(subid) from SomeEntity WHERE id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", jobId).getResultList();
    // Increment old subid by 1
    int subid = resList.get(0);
    SomeEntity.setsubid(subid + 1);
    SomeEntity.setState("ACTIVE");
    // entityManager.merge(SomeEntity);
    entityManager.persist(SomeEntity);
  }
```

i send N concurrent updates from N threads for entity with Id 1 and few other properties as below

SomeEnity entity = new SomeEntity();

```
 entity.setId(1);
  long num = Thread.currentThread().getId();
  entity.setFieldOne("FieldOne" + num);
  entity.setFieldTwo("" + i);
  entity.setFieldThree("" + j);
  i++;
  j++;
```

**Case 1 with  With  `@Id` on id  and `@Id`  annotation on subid and  `entityManager.persist' in update**
When i ran with 300 threads some failed with connection exception "too many connections" The databse state is

```
   id 1 subid 0 
   id 1 subid 1
   id 1 subid 2
   ..  ....
   id 1 subid 150
```

the subid is always incremental ,the race condition is only that which one will be ACTIVE is undefined because of race condition

**Case 2 with  With  `@Id` on id and `@Id`  annotation on subid and `entityManager.merge' in update**

id 1 subid 0 
       id 1 subid 0
       id 2 subid 0
       ..  ....
       id 151 subid 0 (Perhaps just a co-incidence that one more thread  than case 1 was successful? )

**Case 3 With `@GeneratedValue` and `@Id` on id and **NO** `@Id`  annotation on subid  and entityManager.persist in update** 
 exception -- Detached entity passed to persist

**Case 3 With `@GeneratedValue` and `@Id` on id and **NO** `@Id`  annotation on subid  and entityManager.merge in update** 
 if update is run sequentially the database state is

```
id 1 subid 0
```

after next update

```
id 1 subid 1
```

after each update same row is updated (leading to only one row at a time)

```
id 1 subid 2
```

**Case 4 same as Case 3 with Concurrent updates**
  if run concurrently(with 300 threads) i get the below exception

```
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1
```

database state is 
  id 1 subid 2     (Only one thread would have been successful but because of race condition updated subid from 0 to 2 )

**Case 5 With `@GeneratedValue` and `@Id` on id and  `@Id`  annotation on subid**
Create also fails with subid org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of SomeEntity.id

Please explain the causes.From the javadoc of methods i know that

persist - Make an instance managed and persistent.

merge - Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context.

My question is more towards how hibernate manages the annotations.
**Why is there be a detached entity exception in case 3 when the session is not closed yet?** 
**Why is there a IllegalArgumentException in case 5 ?**

I am using hibernate 3.6  mysql 5 and Spring 4
Also please suggest a way achieve such incremental id and subid.(Using custom SelectGenerator ,with a demo implementation or any other way without doing a column concat)

Comment: Updated the question.The id is an auto increment column and works well with hibernate 3.6.5 without @GeneratedValue only that after persisting the id it is not reflected in the object

Comment: It may not happen immediately after persist but it is in a @Transactional method(as mentioned in the linked post) so the value will be reflected outside the transaction.After few tries i figured out that it is happening because of composite primary key

Comment: because the id is auto increment, you can not have multiple rows with the same id, the database will not allow you to set the value for that field. I think the question is incomplete or something is not mentioned correctly.

Comment: see case 1 .Without GeneratedValue annotation it allows to have multiple rows with same Id even if it is auto increment in database because primary key is (id,subid)

Answer (score 3):

Since the `id` field is already unique and auto incremented, you don't need a composite id in this case so your entity can look like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name = "subid")
public int getSubid() {
    return subid;
}
```

The entity can be fetched by id using the entity manager:

```
entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, entityId);
```

or you could fetch the entity using a query that takes both the `id` and the `subid`:

```
MyEntity myEntity = entityManager.createTypeQuery("select me from MyEntity where id = :id and subid = :subid", MyEntity.class)
    .setParameter("id", entityId) 
    .setParameter("subid", entitySubId) 
    .getSingleResult();
```

Hibernate also has a [SelectGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/SelectGenerator.html) that can fetch the id from a database column, which is useful when the database generates the id using a trigger.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with composite ids, so you wither wrote your own extended `SelectGenerator` or use a single string `id_sub_id` column that combines the id and sub-id into a single VARCHAR column:

```
'1-0'
'1-1'
'2-0'
'2-1'
```

You have to write a database trigger to update the two columns using a database specific stored procedure and aggregate the two columns into the VARCHAR one. You then map the aggregated column using the standard `SelectGenerator` to a String field:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id_sub_id")
@GeneratedValue( strategy = "trigger" )
@GenericGenerator( 
    name="trigger", strategy="org.hibernate.id.SelectGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter( name="keys", value="id_sub_id" )
    }
)
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: yes the annotation in my question is not correct but how do i correct it to have multiple subids for a id.On each update i want to increment the subid

Comment: Could you provide some details on implementing a extended SelectGenerator or point to any link.I find it is fairly simply to have custom Identity generator as mentioned here http://supportmycode.com/2014/08/22/custom-id-generator-in-hibernate/ .I can also have two custom id generators for id and subid.Isn't it so?

Comment: Oh ..and i do not find any example implementation of  SelectGenerator .By looking at it's source i assume i have to override getResult .I am still searching for all boilerplate code details to implement a simple logic if id is 0 then id++ version=0 otherwise id remains unchanged version++.It's safe to assume id will be 0 in create calls

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003596/hibernate-does-not-fill-auto-increment-column-being-part-of-composite-pk-bug-or i find that part of the composite key can have GeneratedValue So if i have only one IdentifierGenerator for id field along with @Id on subid then it should work.

Comment: You need to synchronize the id sequence allocation in the database. Doing it in Java will not work across multiple JVM nodes.

Comment: Can you please explain..If " select max(subid) where id= ? " and persist the entity with subid=subid+1 are in same transaction then how would this cause a synchronization issue across multiple jvms ?

Comment: Because nothing prevents two concurrent transactions from trying to insert the same value. You need to lock the table whenever you try to insert, otherwise the check-then-insert operations can be interleaved. You can also test this with a simple test running N concurrent threads trying to insert rows.

Comment: I updated my post with outputs and i see concurrency issue with version only in case 4.Others have concurrency issue that which entity sent for update will be marked active but version is incremental only

Answer (score 2):

> Let's say i have some books with ID and Version.An ID belong to a book
>   which can have many updated versions with latest one being the current
>   version which is what will be mostly queried. What would be a better
>   approach? Should i use a one-to-many mapping

See the design outline below to understand how it should be correctly mapped:

[image]

Saving book:

```
@Transactional
public void saveBook(Book book) {
    em.persist(book);
}
```

Saving book version:

```
@Transactional
public void saveBookVersion(BookVersion bookVersion) {
    Book book = em.find(Book.class, bookVersion.getBook().getId());
    bookVersion.setBook(book);
    book.setLatestBookVersion(bookVersion);
    em.persist(bookVersion);
}
```

Retrieve latest book version:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Book getLatestBookVersion(Long bookId) {
   // it is enough if lastestBookVersion is loaded eagerly
   return em.find(Book.class, bookId);
}
```

Table schema mapping of the logical model above:

[image]

Comment: what is the id in BookVersion table ?Is it the version id or book id(primary key of book) .Can u please add the table schema for book and bookversion to your answer?

Comment: If it is book id then it would be the same problem again with generating the version id(DateIssue as in your answer).The version id is also sequential

Comment: It is id of BookVersion entity / table. That is generally a good practice to have id for each entity / table.

Comment: I recommend you to use id as an internal entity/table identificator only and not use it as a "business" attribute, for example if a book version has some number I would defined it as a separate attribute BookVersion.versionNumber for example. Following this practice helps you to keep mapping clean and straightforward.

Comment: The id in BookVersion table is not auto-increment .Right?

Comment: It depends on id generation strategy you choose (see JPA/Hibernate id generation strategies for complete list) - it maybe autoincrement or not. (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id section: 5.1.2.2. Identifier generator)

Comment: If it is auto increment then it can not have the kind of [bookid,versionid] as in my question [1,0][1,1]...[2,0] [3,0] as versionid will be unique in Bookversion table.Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Just because no one mentioned this.</sub>

> I have a table
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `SomeEntity` (
> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> `subid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`subid`),
> ```
>
> I have a entity class with an auto increment field in it.
>
> [..]
>
> subid is default 0 in database and i am incrementing it programmatically on updates to that row.

**To me this sounds a lot like versioning.**

There is actually an annotation that will do exactly what you want, without you having to write any code:

#### [@Version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html)

> A versioned entity is marked with the `@Version` annotation, 
>   as illustrated in the following code snippet:
>
> ```
> public class User {
>     @ID Integer id;
>     @Version Integer version;
> }
> ```
>
> and its corresponding database schema has a version column, 
>   such as that created by the following SQL statement:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `User` (
>     `id` NUMBER NOT NULL, 
>     `version` NUMBER,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
> );
> ```
>
> The version attribute can be an int, short, long, or timestamp. 
>   **It is incremented when a transaction successfully commits**. 
>   This results in an SQL operation such as the following:
>
> ```
> UPDATE User SET ..., version = version + 1
> WHERE id = ? AND version = readVersion
> ```

*source*: [blogs.oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/locking-and-concurrency-in-java-persistence-20) <sup><sub>(*emphasis mine*)</sub></sup>

I modified the example a bit. I recommend you to use the box types `Integer`, `Long` etc for database fields. Even `id`, which is `NOT NULL`, *will be null* before you save the entity for the first time. I find that using box types makes it explicit that these fields can and will be `null`.